# How can I reduce time for filtering my article dataset?

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to filter my dataset which contains nearly 50K articles. From each article I want to filter out stop words and punctuation. But the process is taking long time. I've already filtered the dataset and it took 6 hours. Now I've got another dataset to filter which contains 300K articles.

I'm using python in anaconda environment. PC configuration: 7th Gen. Core i5, 8GB RAM and NVIDIA 940MX GPU. To filter my dataset I've wrote a code which takes each article in dataset, tokenize words and then remove stop words, punctuations and numbers.

```py
def sentence_to_wordlist(sentence, filters="!\"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n?,।!‍.'0123456789০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯‘\u200c–“”…‘"):
    translate_dict = dict((c, ' ') for c in filters)
    translate_map = str.maketrans(translate_dict)
    wordlist = sentence.translate(translate_map).split()
    global c,x;
    return list(filter(lambda x: x not in stops, wordlist))
```

Now I want to reduce the time for this process. Is there any way to optimize this?

Comment: Can you provide an input example and expected output ?

Comment: data = ['they have got 7 players in their team']; then I just put it in the function like: words = sentence_to_wordlist(data[0]) and it returns tokenized sentence like:
 ['they','got','players', 'their', 'team'], where words in *stops* are filtered out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been trying to optimize your process:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

cachedStopWords = set(stopwords.words("english"))

filters = "!\"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n?,।!‍.'0123456789০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯‘\u200c–“”…‘"
trnaslate_table = str.maketrans('', '', filters)
def sentence_to_wordlist(sentence, filters=filters):
    wordlist = sentence.translate(trnaslate_table).split()
    return [w for w in wordlist if w not in cachedStopWords] 

from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

p = Pool(10)
results  = p.map(sentence_to_wordlist, data)
```

- data is a list with your articles
- I've been using the stop words from nltk but you can use your own stopwords, please make sure your stopwords is a set not a list ([because to find if a element is in a set is O(1) time complexity and in a list is O(n)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity))

I've been testing with a list of 100k articles, each article having around 2k characters, took me less than 9 seconds.

Comment: yes, it has worked like magic! Only taking the stopwords as set has solved the time complexity. Thank You!

Comment: @rusu_ro1 , the way you have solved his problem, is there any effect of multiprocessing.pool?

Comment: what do you mean by effect ? you can have a look here https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing.html